# Permission Denial requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

Hello this is quite strange, I give permissions inside my manifest + in code for Android 23+. It looks like :

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},   1001);
    }
```

While I'm trying to save photo (during that I insert some data to Database) I'm getting error :

```
   E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=31226, uid=10131 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Strange fact is that app seems to works correctly but I'm getting this errors in logs.

Comment: Every permission is enabled in Settings -> Apps -> Your app -> Permissions?

Comment: This code in onCreate enabling it. Like I said app seems to works correctly but I still getting this errors.

Comment: Can you post the whole manifest?

Comment: @bzmg I can but it's is quite useless rest stuff is just activities declaration services etc.

Comment: Where do you call the MediaProvider function to read?